# Audio Appending using RandomAccessFile

Tags: android, audio

I use the following code to append as many wav files present in the sdcard to a single file. audFullPath is an arraylist containing the path of the audiofiles. Is it correct. When I play the recordedaudio1, after doing this. It play only the first file. I want to play all the files. Any suggestion..

```
File file=new File("/sdcard/AudioRecorder/recordedaudio1.wav");

RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");

for(int i=0;i<audFullPath.size();i++) {
    f=new File(audFullPath.get(i));      
    fileContent = new byte[(int)f.length()];
    System.out.println("Filecontent"+fileContent);
    raf.seek(raf.length()); 
    raf.writeBytes(audFullPath.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't append `WAV` files the way you do. That's because each `WAV` has special format:

The simplest possible `WAV` file looks like this:

```
[RIFF HEADER]
...
totalFileSize    

[FMT CHUNK]
...
audioFormat
frequency
bytesPerSample
numberOfChannels
...

[DATA CHUNK]
dataSize
<audio data>
```

What you need to do is:

1. Make sure that all `WAV` files are of compatible: same audioFormat, frequency, bits per sample, number of channels, etc.
2. Create proper `RIFF` header with total file size
3. Create proper `FMT` header
4. Create proper `DATA` header with total audio data size

This algorithm will definitely work for LPCM, ULAW, ALAW audio formats. Not sure about others.

Comment: It will work for PCM. The WAV file format is described here: http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/documents/audioformats/wave/wave.html; And also here: http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/wavefiles.html.