# How to pause/resume a recording created with mediarecorder?

Tags: java, android, append, audio-recording, mediarecorder

I'm trying to pause a recording on an incoming call and resume it later. i'm using the andriod `mediarecorder` and trying to record in `MPEG4`. I tried pause/resume with resetting/stopping a recording and starting it with the `setOutputFile(fd)`, `fd` being the `filedescriptor` of the audio file that was stopped/paused and hoped it would append but i had no luck. Is there a way to achieve this or append two recordings or should i give up on `mediarecorder`.

**code:**

```
private MediaRecorder media_recorder;
private String file_path = null;

public void startRecording(path)
{
  file_path = path
  media_recorder= new MediaRecorder();
  media_recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
  media_recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
  media_recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
  media_recorder.setOputputFile(path);
  media_recorder.prepare();
}

public void pauseRecording()
{
  media_recorder.stop();
  media_recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
  media_recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
  media_recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
  FileOutputStream paused_file = new FileOutputStream(file_path);
  media_recorder.setOutputFile(paused_file.getFD());
}

public void resumeRecording()
{
  media_recorder.prepare();
  media_recorder.start();
}
```

`pauseRecording()` stops the recording but resume fails with message `start failed`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer for your question is **NO YOU CAN'T**

`Once you are recording the only possible actions are stop and reset.`

So try to save your Call  to SDCard after you Stop , and then again start Fresh Record and Stop it. `Finally Combine both Audio File into one Audio file`.

Record the audio as .wav file and [Combine using this format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179709/audio-appending-using-randomaccessfile).

Comment: any idea on how to append two m4a files?

Comment: @Pannu Did you check the post?

Comment: Yes, although its helpful I believe its about merging `WAVE/PCM` files. Will not work for `m4a (MPEG-4)`.

Comment: @Pannu Upto my knowledge we can Combine only .wav and RAW_AMR format files.

Comment: well I'm going to port `mEncoder` or `ffmpeg` to android and try merging, seems like a possible solution.

Comment: No it kept crashing. My mind boggles when i think how popular android is and still this is impossible. :(

Comment: @Pannu, have you found a viable solution to this issue? What can be done to pause/resume from MediaRecorder. Are appending stream data or merging files the only solutions?

Comment: @portfoliobuilder: nope.. I had to create a temp file for each pause and then merge them using a ported mencoder binary to andriod. It makes me sick to look at that code but that's all I've got now. Although there are lot of ports available for ffmpeg.

Comment: Just an update. MediaRecorder.pause is coming out soon.

Comment: Update came with API 24. Now it's possible to pause and resume recorder.