# Can we pause the camera while recording

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, video-recording

In my application I have timer driven video recording functionality. When the camera is in recording mode and if I click on a button on anywhere on the screen the recording should pause. I should be able to continue recording on clicking again.

But there is no pause action for recording video in many of the android devices.

Is there any other ways of doing it? I found this [***link***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8008062/1237656) but it doesn't give me any hope.

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't do that as no inbuilt function is there what you can do it is that whenever you want to pause your app, stop it and start another part, then combine all parts of it...

**Edit:** If you are using the MediaRecorder, you can use MediaRecorder.Pause() + .Resume() from Android 7.0 (Nougat, API 24) or higher