# MediaRecorder.pause() in android

Tags: android, api, mediarecorder, pause

the pause method added to MediaRecorder in api 24

is there any way to use this in a older api?

[here is android studio suggest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyW38.png)
but i want use it in older devices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer for your question is NO YOU CAN'T

Once you are recording the only possible actions are stop and reset.

So try to save your Call to SDCard after you Stop , and then again start Fresh Record and Stop it. Finally Combine both Audio File into one Audio file.

Record the audio as .wav file and [Combine using this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179709/audio-appending-using-randomaccessfile).

Answer (score 0):

On older platforms there is no `MediaRecorder.pause()`. The only option is to record few separate files and then concatenate it by yourself with any available library (e.g. try FFmpeg-based). But note that there may be roughness due recorder may insert empty frames at the begin / end of files and concatenated media may contain artifacts like blinking, cracks so on.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [library](https://gitlab.com/axet/android-audio-recorder).
I have personally used this to add pause and resume functionalities to my android app. It supports all API levels.

Comment: Try to explain what you are suggesting and how to use that. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers